# Shouldn't Python install packages in the directory of it's own?

Tags: python, pip

I have

```
C:\>where pip3
C:\Python35\Scripts\pip3.exe
C:\Python36\Scripts\pip3.exe
```

on my Windows 10 box. Simultaneously, when I ran

```
pip3 install --upgrade --user awscli
```

I got `aws.cmd` located in

```
C:\Users\Dmitry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\Scripts
```

Was this misconfiguration or expected behavior of `awscli` installer?

Comment: is `AppData\Roaming\Python` not a reasonable place to keep application data?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I don't know. I used `Chocolatey` to install Python and thought it has intalled Python on C and that all pip installations will go there. The problem is not that some place is good or bad, the problem is that there are many places, where python installations go.

Comment: There are two types of files, those used in the execution of the program which only changes when it's updated and the application data (resources) which is used when the program is running but are not critical to it's execution.  I'd expect pip to install packages to the AppData folder but I do see your point about the scripts going there too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the `--user` option, and the documentation says

> Passing the `--user` option to python -m pip install will install a package just for the current user, rather than for all users of the system.

If the package is supposed to be user-specific it can't go in `C:\Python*`, because those are system-wide directories, and all users would share them.

So, yes, it's expected that when you request a user-specific installation, the package goes in a user-specific directory.