# trying to install label-studio with Python

Tags: python, pip, python-venv, label-studio

I'm trying to install label-studio library following the web-site information:
[enter link description here](https://labelstud.io/guide/install)

In particular I'm using the following commands:

```
pip install label-studio --user
```

The module is correctly installed in the folder: c:\users*******\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages.

But I get the following error when I run the command `label-studio start`:

```js
label-studio : The term 'label-studio' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or  
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ label-studio
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (label-studio:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Or if I run `python -m label-studio`, I get this error:

```
C:\Python311\python.exe: No module named label-studio
```

I also tried with the following installation method:

```html
python3 -m venv c:\path\to\myenv
c:\path\to\myenv\Scripts\activate.bat
python -m pip install label-studio --user
```

But when I run the command `label-studio` I get the same error.

Finally if I use the following commands:

```html
python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
python -m pip install label-studio
```

I get the following error in the `source env/bin/activate` command:

```html
source : The term 'source' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path wa
s included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ source env/bin/activate
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (source:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: Try to run it via python: `python -m label-studio`

Comment: I get this error: C:\Python311\python.exe: No module named label-studio

Comment: And what happens when you try to install it, what is the output of your command `pip install label-studio --user`?

Comment: The module is correctly installed in the folder c:\users\********\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better practice to install python libraries in virtual environment.

First create virtual environment using

```
python -m venv <ENV_NAME>
```

For activating use following command

```
<ENV_NAME>\Scripts\activate
```

Install label-studio with

```
pip install label-studio
```

and finally start the label-studio using following command

```
label-studio
```

Comment: Your answer is working. But is there a way to run label-studio without using virtual environment?

Comment: Please refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44005928/10456732

Comment: Also looks like your path `c:\users*******\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages`  is not in PATH environment variable.